# How to make 0.3% ammonia water from 28-30% ammonia hydroxide

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, teaching-lab

Can someone tell me how to make 0.3% ammonia water from 28-30% Ammonia hydroxide?
I am trying to make a gallon or 3.78 Liters.

Comment: ***Hint*** : Ammonia water is actually diluted Ammonium Hydroxide ruled by the following equilibrium : $$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + HO-}$$

Comment: Is it a question for homework/study or you need it for an experiment? I am asking because ammonia is volatile: if you need this solution with accurate concentration/pH, you also should be able to measure somehow what you get at hand.

Answer (score -1):

Ammonium hydroxide does not exist. $\ce{NH4OH}$ is a formula that was invented in the 19th century to explain why $\ce{NH3}$ is so easily and exothermically dissolved into water, as if there was a chemical reaction with water. But it has been proven that as soon as an ion like $\ce{NH4^+}$ meets the ion $\ce{OH^-}$, the following reaction occurs : $$\ce{NH4^+ + OH- <=> NH3 + H2O}$$ But this equilibrium is strongly displaced to the right hand side. So that a solution of $\ce{NH3}$ contains only a few percent of ammonium ions.

Anyway the concentration of the so-called "concentrated $\ce{NH4OH}$" does not contain $29$% $\ce{NH4OH}$, but it contains $29$% of $\ce{NH3}$.

Now to produce a solution containing $\pu{0.3}$%  $\ce{NH3}$ with this concentrated solution (density : $\pu{0.91 g/mL}$), it is necessary to dilute it $100$ times. In other words, take $\pu{37.8 g = 41.5 mL}$ into one gallon water ($\pu{3.78 L}$)

Comment: What about density ?